# Why are my strings not being validated by double equals and characters are not being appended as they should to the end

Tags: c#

So I am a Software Packager and I am working on a little project for my company to automate the packaging of some of the free software available via Ninite and Chocolatey. I have managed to get the Ninite stuff working fine but Chocolatey is proving to be a pain.

This section of the code is supposed to compare the app versions from my `.csv` to data returned from querying chocolatey via cmd.exe.

If the versions don't match I have some other classes that deal with updating the `.csv` with the latest available version and the rest of the code creates some config files to be used by the other software I am dealing with. This bit is irrelevant as I have managed to get it to work. It's simply just the fact that for some unknown reason the strings returned from querying chocolatey are not behaving as they should.

I initially thought the issue may have been caused by the way I was using `.Replace()` to filter unwanted data but at this point if I remove all instances of `.Replace()` and just simply use the data stored in line I get the same results.

The issue seems to lay somewhere in the `GetChocApps()` method and the print outs are from the `CompareVersions()` method.

(Sorry if I have provided a tad more code than I should have but I personally thought it was all relevant)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace XXXX_PackagingAutomation
{
    class Choc
    {
        private Dictionary<string, string> chocApps = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        private Dictionary<string, string> csvApps = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // For each app a new entry is to be added
        // Key: Name in Chocolatey
        // Value: Name to appear in CSV
        private Dictionary<string, string> chocAppsToCheck = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            {"adobereader", "Adobe_Acrobat_Reader_DC"}
        };

        private List<Data> csvData; // Used to hold csv data passed in from Main method


        #region Run
        public void Run(List<Data> csvDataIn)
        {
            csvData = csvDataIn;
            GetChocApps();
            CsvAppsToDic();     // Place all the CSV apps along with corresponding versions to csvApps dictionary
            CompareVersions();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Get Choc Apps
        private void GetChocApps()
        {
            foreach (var appName in chocAppsToCheck)
            {
                List<string> chocoTempList = new List<string>();

                ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    Arguments = $"/c choco search {appName.Key} --exact",
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                };

                //Process.Start(procStartInfo);

                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                p.Start();

                StreamReader outputWriter = p.StandardOutput;
                string errorReader = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                string lines = outputWriter.ReadToEnd();

                string[] individualLines = lines.Split("\n"[0]);



                // All lines returned from the command are then added to the chocoTempList
                foreach (string line in individualLines)
                    chocoTempList.Add(line);

                p.WaitForExit();


                foreach (string line in chocoTempList)
                {
                    // If the line contains the information we are looking for then we add it to the choco dictionaries
                    if (!line.Contains("Chocolatey v") && !line.Contains("packages found") && line.Contains(appName.Key))
                    {
                        #region Adobe Acrobat Reader DC
                        if (appName.Key == "adobereader")
                        {
                            // Filter the line to exclude anything else other than the version which is what we want
                            // and then assign it to the version variable. 
                            string version = line.Replace($"{appName.Key} ", "").Replace(" [Approved]", "").Replace(".", "-").Replace("/n", "");

                            // Add the Name and version to the chocoApps dictionary from the chocoTempList
                            chocApps.Add(appName.Value, version);
                        }
                        #endregion
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region CSV apps to Dictionary
        private void CsvAppsToDic()
        {
            foreach (var app in csvData)
                csvApps.Add(app.name, app.version);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Compare Versions
        private void CompareVersions()
        {
            // Run this for each entry in the chocApps Dictionary
            foreach (var cApp in chocApps)
            {
                // If the 
                foreach (var app in csvApps)
                {
                    // Find the matching name
                    if (app.Key == cApp.Key)
                    {
                        // Check if versions match
                        if (app.Value == cApp.Value)
                        {
                            // If the versions match
                            //Global.WriteVersion()
                            Console.WriteLine("Versions match :D");
                            Console.WriteLine($"{app.Value}a");
                            Console.WriteLine($"{cApp.Value}a");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // If they don't match
                            Console.WriteLine("This Version should have matched but it doesn't match :(\nRaw print outs:");
                            Console.WriteLine($"{cApp.Value}"); // chocoApps Dict
                            Console.WriteLine($"{app.Value}");  // csvApps Dict

                            // Heres where the funny bit happens :D
                            // Note how I have added some characters to the end of the line *abc
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
                            Console.WriteLine($"{cApp.Value}*abc"); // chocoApps Dict
                            Console.WriteLine($"{app.Value}*abc");  // csvApps Dict
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

This else statement should not have been called since the two strings should have matched.

Here's a screenshot which includes the console output of the running code.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can convert the cApp.Value and app.Value strings into character arrays and compare those to help investigate what the problem might be

Comment: It might very well be how you're using `Replace`.  Did you mean `"/n"` or did you really mean `"\n"`?  The difference is two characters, `'/'` and `'n'`, vs. one LF character.

Answer (score 0):

it might just be case of white space, try:

```
if (app.Value.Trim() == cApp.Value.Trim())
{
    //etc
}
```

edit:  Trim() removes all white space at the start and end of the string including \r and \n also, so will also fix your issue above due to /n i.e. replace .Replace("/n","") with Trim() where you assign the string.  Covers a number of issues with simpler code.